# How to change the height of v-text-field

Tags: vuetify.js

change v-text-field height, but not work

set height in style but not work

```
<v-text-field v-if="item.title === '用户'" hide-details light solo append-icon="search" style="width: 150px; height: 50px; margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 8px" label="搜索联系人" v-model="selectedUser" v-on:input="searchUser"></v-text-field>
```

want less height

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the height in the style. Use the props of the element: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields

Which version you are using?

```
<v-text-field
  height="20px"
  label="Regular"
></v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try **dense** prop as given below.
This will reduce the height of v-text-field.

```
<v-text-field
        label="Outlined"
        outlined
        dense
></v-text-field>
```

Answer (score -1):

Example, using 36px.

```css
.v-text-field--filled.v-input--dense.v-text-field--single-line > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot, .v-text-field--filled.v-input--dense.v-text-field--outlined > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot, .v-text-field--filled.v-input--dense.v-text-field--outlined.v-text-field--filled > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot, .v-text-field--full-width.v-input--dense.v-text-field--single-line > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot, .v-text-field--full-width.v-input--dense.v-text-field--outlined > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot, .v-text-field--full-width.v-input--dense.v-text-field--outlined.v-text-field--filled > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot, .v-text-field--outlined.v-input--dense.v-text-field--single-line > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot, .v-text-field--outlined.v-input--dense.v-text-field--outlined > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot, .v-text-field--outlined.v-input--dense.v-text-field--outlined.v-text-field--filled > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot {
    min-height: 36px;
}
```

`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).